# ALL GCM parameters?

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

i´ve written a "pushserver" for my app via PHP.
The push notifications i´ve sent via PHP are all received on the device, so far.
But, i can just send/set the "message" and "title", see:

```
        $fields = array(
            'registration_ids' => $registrationIDs,
            'data' => array(
                'message' => $message,
                'title' => 'My App',
                'vibrate' => 1,
                'sound' => 1,
                'icon' => "http://example.com/image.jpg",
                "style" => "inbox"
            ),
        );
```

"icon" and "style" are not working (vibrate and sound not tested, yet).
Every link for the parameters i´ve found is broken or kind of "you need to do object.setSomething() in JAVA.

Is there a list anywhere where i can see ALL parameters, which i can send to GCM? No matter, what language i use?

Cheers,
Chris

Comment: Checked the docs? https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

couple of things need to keep in mind while all the data which you sending from server end

Is there a list anywhere where i can see ALL parameters,

exp :- you can send as many parameters as you want but offcourse there is limitation but not key specific just like you can use "textmessage" instead of "message" but make sure to retrieve the value from same key which you are assigning from server end

1) please make sure that you are getting all the data in gcmintentservice class try to print the log of all intent data.

please remember that this is just a string data it is not going to download the image for you. you have to download using volley library or any suitable library

Comment: ok, so it doesnt really matter, which parameters i send? so the problem is more like the "workaround" at "receiving notifications" in my app? it´s phonegap. so, i need to check out the pushplugin, right?

Comment: i never played around phonegap but it is 100% sure that you can send any parameter and can receive it from android end in spite of any framework you are using.
you must check in your android code .

Comment: Thanks for that! So it was just some Kind of misunderstanding HOW it works from my side. Thanks! :-)